# Outputting the same generated number value

Tags: arrays, sorting, generator

Do anyone of you know how to keep a random number generator value the same when i output it? I'm currently creating a leader board where it allows user to enter their name, enter how many player are playing, and have a random number generator generate 10 value and adding them together into one total score. So far, I have generated the total score and i plan to output as "Welcome (player name) your total score is (total score value)", this process is then repeated until all player's name is outputted. After that, i plan to use an array and array sort to display the player's score from highest to lowest. But the problem is that i don't know how do i keep the "total score" value the same as the one i displayed to the one that outputs the player's name and score and the "leaderboard" since the random number generator will keep generating new number values. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. Here is what i have done so far

```js
< HTML >
  < !Foundation Page
for building our Javascript programs >
  < HEAD >
  < TITLE > The Foundation Page < /TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">

function main()
{
 start()
 randomnumber()
 totalscore()
 leaderboard()
}
function start()
{
 var ask
 var name1
 var name2
 var name3
 var name4
 var name5
 
 
 ask=prompt ("How many people are playing")
 if (ask==3)
  {
  name1=prompt("What is the first player's name?")
  name2=prompt("What is the second player's name?")
  name3=prompt("What is the third player's name?")
  }
 if (ask==4)
  {
  name1=prompt("What is the first player's name?")
  name2=prompt("What is the second player's name?")
  name3=prompt("What is the third player's name?")
  name4=prompt("What is the forth player's name?")
  }
 if (ask==5)
  {
  name1=prompt("What is the first player's name?")
  name2=prompt("What is the second player's name?")
  name3=prompt("What is the third player's name?")
  name4=prompt("What is the forth player's name?")
  name5=prompt("What is the fifth player's name?")
  }  
}

function randomnumber()
{
 var randomnumber;
 randomnumber = Math.random()*3;
 return(Math.floor(randomnumber+0.5));
}
function totalscore() 
{
 var n;
 var score = 0;
 for (n=0; n<10; n=n+1)
 {
  number = randomnumber();
  if (number == 0)
   {
    score =score+0;
   }
  else if (number == 2)
   {
    score =score+2;
   }
  else if (number == 3)
   {
    score =score+3;
   }
 }
 document.write (score)
}
function leaderboard ()
{
 var leaderboardarray = new array (5);

  leaderboardarray[0] = number;
  leaderboardarray[1] = number;
  leaderboardarray[2] = number;
  leaderboardarray[3] = number;
  leaderboardarray[4] = number;
 


}
</SCRIPT >
  < HEAD >
  < BODY >
  < BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE" >
  < H2 > The Foundation Page < /H2>
<HR>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript"> main() </SCRIPT >
  < INPUT NAME = "dobutton"
TYPE = "button"
value = "Start game"
on Click = "game()" >
  < INPUT NAME = "dobutton"
TYPE = "button"
value = "Leaderboard"
on Click = "leader()" >
  < /BODY>
</HTML >
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what's being asked here but just a few points to make:

- Your name variables could be made into an array of names with the size specified by ask. i.e instead of names1-5 you could do

  ```
  var names[ask]
  ```

  so it creates an array of names where the size is the amount of players specified. Then prompting for names you could have somethings along the lines

  ```
  for(var i = 1; i < ask; i++) {
     names[i] = prompt("Name of Player " + i);
  }
  ```
- In totalScore your if else checks for number are pointless because you're always going to be adding number to score and it will always be between 0 and 3 so instead of checking it's value to add, just add it:

  ```
  number = randomNumber();
  score += number;
  ```
- Your formatting in general is pretty poor and you should use lower case for the tags and no spaces i.e

  ```
  < HTML >
  ```

  should be

  ```
  <html>
  ```

  similarly with all tags
- Note: The above are tips that I think you should take on board for future work!
- If you could clarify what exactly you want to do with the above code that would be great and I'd be glad to try help!

Comment: Sorry about that, im pretty bad at explaining things. What im trying to do is to output the same "score" random number generated value twice.  The reason for this is because i wanted to output a leaderboard which shows the score from the highest score to lowest and i also want to output the same score value (the same value at the leaderboard) with the player's name next to the score to allow the user to see their score at the leaderboard. I hope this is easier for you to understand